# Data loading concurrency limits in Azure SQL DW

Tags: azure-synapse

In PDW, you can have 10 loads running concurrently and up to 40 queued, then the 51st will fail. What about for Azure SQL DW?

This [page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-concurrency/) mentions the DWU/concurrency numbers. Does data loading (through bulk load and Polybase) also follow the 32 concurrent query limit? What happens if you try to run 33 concurrent loads? Is there a max queue depth?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These loading concurrency limits do not apply to Bulk Load and PolyBase operations. As these are currently the available loading mechanisms for SQL DW, when loading you will only be limited by the restrictions placed on currently running queries. The page that you have linked to lays out the concurrency limits. If these limits are exceeded, queries will queue up to 1000 and then will fail after the queue is full.